# User can not publish

Tags: 2011, publishing

[image: Permission]

I have given the Group above permission on the publication, however, the publication target is not showing up for the user in this group. (It is showing up for the admin user). Did I miss anything on the permission setting?

Answer (score 7):

OK. I found out the answer myself. I need to add this group into the Publication Management | Target Type.

Comment: Nice catch and thanks for following up. Btw, if you have lots of Groups that should access the same Target Type you could make them members of a "shared" (parent) Group.